# Android L - Material design on SwipeRefreshLayout color scheme

Tags: colors, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I´m starting to implement the Material Theme on my newest project, preparing it for the launch of the new L version.

I´ve been reading the Material design guidelines and found this.

> **UI Color Application**
>
> *Choose your palette*
>
> Limit your choice of colors by choosing three color hues in the
>   primary and one accent color in the secondary palette. The accent
>   color may or may not need fall back options

More or less it explains how to implement those hues on the app, including the accent color but when using the main color on my app with the SwipeRefreshLayout progress bar, it doesn't feel right.

[image: App example SwipeRefreshLayout Material design]

Should it be a mix between the accent color and the `android:colorPrimary`?

Any thoughts about this? Is there any explanation about implementing progress bars on the Material design guideline that I´ve missed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32460907/8237188  answer might be helpful .

Answer (score 156, accepted):

The Material design spec has been updated with the new guidelines for the [swipe to refresh pattern](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/swipe-to-refresh.html).

As of revision 21 of the support library, `SwipeRefreshLayout` now displays a circular indicator.
When you start swiping down, the indicator has an arrow (which suggests refreshing). When you release it, it loses the arrow and starts spinning.

[image: SwipeRefreshLayout]

Now we can still set a color scheme and the progress bar will cycle between the colors.

So which colors should we use?

Let's take a look at the Google I/O [source code](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/BaseActivity.java):

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(
                R.color.refresh_progress_1,
                R.color.refresh_progress_2,
                R.color.refresh_progress_3);
```

And here are the [colors](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/res/values/colors.xml):

```
<color name="refresh_progress_1">@color/theme_accent_2</color>
<color name="refresh_progress_2">@color/theme_accent_1</color>
<color name="refresh_progress_3">@color/theme_primary</color>
```

So yes, it is a mix between the primary and the accent colors.

Comment: Well, it looks like its in an early state right now. Good answer by the way. I'll keep it open a little bit more and if by the end of the week there's no better one I'll accept it.

Comment: This is awful. They should at least let us choose which design we like more. Their own material design styled apps use bars as pull to refresh indicators.

Comment: @Kuno you can get linear progress code from here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.L_preview/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.java

Comment: Yep, that's what I ended up with. You have to copy BakedBezierInterpolator, SwipeProgressBar and SwipeRefreshLayout.

Comment: It is more convenient to create an array of colors in colors.xml and use that for some people http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118038/how-to-pass-int-array-of-color-resource-ids-from-array-xml-to-swiperefreshlayout

Comment: Shadow doesn't appear in Samsung Note 5

Answer (score 0):

Given solution did not work for me.

I simple extended and used this instead.

```
class SwipeToRefreshLayout(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): SwipeRefreshLayout(context, attrs)  {

var listener: OnRefreshListener? = null

fun setRefreshing(refreshing: Boolean, fireCallback: Boolean) {
    super.setRefreshing(refreshing)
    listener?.onRefresh()
}

override fun setOnRefreshListener(listener: OnRefreshListener?) {
    super.setOnRefreshListener(listener)
    this.listener = listener
}
}
```

I hope someone finds it helpful.