# How to change the style progerssbar in SwipeRefreshLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I use SwipeRefreshLayout to update my list.

everything works. but I do not like the progress bar. It is round. and carried the arrow to spin. I have seen examples in which a strip of moving from the center to the edges. How to set up a progress bar style?

```
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;
...
swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_guest_list);
        swipeLayout.setColorSchemeColors(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
```

[example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SxOuSneMZsU) I need both the video

Comment: SwipeRefreshLayout UI has been changed on new material design pattern (http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/swipe-to-refresh.html) without giving choice to choose. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995480/android-l-material-design-on-swiperefreshlayout-color-scheme

Comment: Yes, exactly what I have up and running. What do I do if I want a progress bar like in the old version? I am not absolutely satisfied with circular progressbar

Comment: I hope (atleast now) the only way to get the old style SwipeRefreshLayout is to get the file(s) from the AOSP version control system

Comment: I measured with this style (yet) but I can not set the transparency background on the progress bar! can you help? do not want to start a new topic.
      swipeLayout.setProgressBackgroundColor(Color.RED); an error!
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffff0000

Comment: setProgressBackgroundColor only accepts resource id of the color and not the color id. Put the necessary color in colors.xml and get it as getResources().getColor(R.color.XXX)

Comment: swipeLayout.setProgressBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.employe_negative));
so I did too. The same error

Comment: Check swipeLayout.setProgressBackgroundColor(R.c‌​olor.employe_negative); also let me know the color xml of employe_negative

Comment: <color name="employe_negative">#ccffcc</color>

Comment: swipeLayout.setProgressBackgroundColor(android.R.color.darker_gray); so works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SwipeRefreshLayout: Swipe progress animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099755/swiperefreshlayout-swipe-progress-animation)

Answer (score 5):

This Is My Example

webframe = WebView

swipeContainer = swipeLayout

```
swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener {
        webframe.reload()
        swipeContainer.setColorSchemeColors(Color.WHITE)
        swipeContainer.setProgressBackgroundColorSchemeColor(Color.rgb(0,165,165))
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can actually change it to the older progress bar one, by **giving reference** to the **older jar file of the support-v4** library. I had the same issue suddenly after updating eclipse, i just copied the older support-v4.jar to projects libs folder and then using project properties references this support-v4.jar and then clean and built the project and now it was using the old classes.
This solution is **suitable if you are not using anything particular from the updated support library**.

Answer (score 2):

You can play with different colors of the swipe's progress var:

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.blue, R.color.green, R.color.orange);
```

where blue, green and orange are defined in colors.xml

***setColorSchemeResources*** receives a *varargs*, so you can play with the number of colors there

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the animation.

In `SwipeRefreshLayout` you can't customize much; I believe this is an attempt of Google to get developers stick to common patterns. What you can style are the four colors of the animation, specified with `setColorScheme()`.

`SwipeRefreshLayout` takes care to show its predefined animation at its top for you. This can be when `canChildScrollUp()` returns false and user 'pulls down', or when you set `setRefreshing(true)`. Turn off the animation with `setRefreshing(false)`. Put your logic in the method `onRefreshing()` of the listener. Override `canChildScrollUp()` if you put something that is not a `ListView` in your `SwipeRefreshLayout`. You should be good to go from here.

Comment: This is copied verbatim from the accepted answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099755/swiperefreshlayout-swipe-progress-animation)