# How can you change a Swipe refresh layout's color for each rotation?

Tags: android

Has anyone noticed the `SwipeRefreshLayout` in gmail. It changes color for every rotation in a single load iteration. Does anyone have any idea how to achieve it?

Comment: You should show part of your code and not asking for a full code implementation. The way to achieve that is by using setColorScheme in the Swipe Refresh object. It allows you to set 4 colors.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) for `SwipeRefreshLayout` details the `setColorSchemeResources()` and `setColorSchemeColors()` methods that can be used to set the color scheme of your `SwipeRefreshLayout`

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#setColorSchemeColors(int...)) state:

> Set the color resources used in the progress animation from color resources. The first color will also be the color of the bar that grows in response to a user swipe gesture.

You should note that `setColorSchemeColors()` should be used with specific colour values and `setColorSchemeResources()` should be used when you intend to use resource references to colours (e.g. `R.color.red`).

Please also note that `setColorScheme()`, the old way of completing this, is now *deprecated*.

Comment: In my case setColorSchemeColors() and setColorSchemeResources() only changes the color of arrow, ring progress color remains white

Comment: @RajeshKoshti As the docs state, this changes the progress animation color and **not** the view

Comment: then what should i do for change the color of progress ring?

Comment: @RajeshKoshti as far as I am aware, you can't

Comment: i am adding swipe to refreshlayout with recyclerview inside fragment but unable to change color of progress indicator it is displaying white, i am able to change the background color of progress indicator using setProgressBackgroundColor method but not able to change color of progress ring

Comment: @RajeshKoshti Please seek advice for this in a new StackOverflow question should one not already exist that asks this question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125334/discussion-between-rajesh-koshti-and-ed-george).

Comment: @RajeshKoshti To change the background of the swipe refresh circle you should use `setProgressBackgroundColorSchemeResource()` method. Better late than never)

Answer (score 31):

Change colors as per UI requirement:

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW, Color.BLUE);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you can get the colors from the colors.xml resource and set them as SwipRefreshLayout's color scheme.

```
int c1 = getResources().getColor(R.color.refresh_progress_1);
int c2 = getResources().getColor(R.color.refresh_progress_2);
int c3 = getResources().getColor(R.color.refresh_progress_3);

mySwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(c1, c2, c3);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.simpleSwipeRefreshLayout);

swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener()
 {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

                // implement Handler to wait for 3 seconds and then update UI means update value of TextView
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // cancle the Visual indication of a refresh
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.Aqua,R.color.Blue,R.color.Violet);
                        // Generate a random integer number
                        Random r = new Random();
                        int i1 = r.nextInt(80 - 65) + 65;
                        // set the number value in TextView
                        textView.setText(String.valueOf(i1));
                    }
                }, 3000);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation with your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I made xml with <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout ...> and config in MainActivity.java,This above code generate random number when you pulldown screen with mullticolor progressdialog.This example is defined using swiperefresh layout.

Answer (score -1):

you can use any of those either passing Colors values or Colors Resource Ids

- Passing Colors

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors({COLOR VALUE},{COLOR VALUE },
any number of colors values..., {COLOR VALUE});
```

- Passing Colors Resources Ids

````
swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources( R.color.{your Color resource Id},
any number of colors ids... , R.color.{your Color resource Id})```
````

Answer (score -1):

In my case the

> setColorSchemeColors(R.color.primary), directly adding the color(Color.parse("#ffbea12")) instead of resource reference should work but I had to use the resources

and

> setColorSchemeResources(R.color.primary) Both did not work as expected

Then I found that in colors.xml I had missing

```
 <color name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</color>
```

So after adding it like this I GOT the desired color